# Can't read data from hash using column(:) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> a = {"item"=>{"id"=>"34567", "name"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23",
>   "description"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "unit_price"=>"2342",
>   "item_type"=>"Inventory", "track_qty_on_hand"=>"true",
>   "qty_on_hand"=>"50000", "inv_start_date"=>{"(3i)"=>"4", "(2i)"=>"5",
>   "(1i)"=>"2016"}}, "company_id"=>"1", "item_type"=>"Inventory",
>   "amount"=>"1232"}

Output:

> a['item'] = {"id"=>"34567", "name"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23",
>   "description"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "unit_price"=>"2342",
>   "item_type"=>"Inventory", "track_qty_on_hand"=>"true",
>   "qty_on_hand"=>"50000", "inv_start_date"=>{"(3i)"=>"4", "(2i)"=>"5",
>   "(1i)"=>"2016"}}
>
> a[:item] = nil

So, How to get data as a[:item]. What I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [symbolize_keys](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys) to change symbolize keys of hash

```
a = {"item"=>{"id"=>"34567", "name"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "description"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "unit_price"=>"2342", "item_type"=>"Inventory", "track_qty_on_hand"=>"true", "qty_on_hand"=>"50000", "inv_start_date"=>{"(3i)"=>"4", "(2i)"=>"5", "(1i)"=>"2016"}}, "company_id"=>"1", "item_type"=>"Inventory", "amount"=>"1232"}

output =  a.symbolize_keys
```

result:

```
{:item=>{"id"=>"34567", "name"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "description"=>"AAX item 1 Inventory23", "unit_price"=>"2342", "item_type"=>"Inventory", "track_qty_on_hand"=>"true", "qty_on_hand"=>"50000", "inv_start_date"=>{"(3i)"=>"4", "(2i)"=>"5", "(1i)"=>"2016"}}, :company_id=>"1", :item_type=>"Inventory", :amount=>"1232"}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer

Answer (score 1):

`'item'` is a string.
`:item` is a symbol.

You can convert a string to a symbol with the `.to_sym` method, so this would work:

```
a['item'.to_sym]
```

or declare it as a symbol from the beginning.

```
a = { :item => {"id"=>"3...
```

Also, this method changes all the keys in your hash to symbols:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys